# JQuery one page auto scroll with menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've been puzzleing over this for a few days and not been able to resolve it. Please can you lend some assistance?

Im trying to create an effect like this: http://www.beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA9

I have created some code using the scrollit js but when I add anchors it gives a bounce effect as the scrollit kicks in to say got to a specific page height.

Can you see a way to create the same functionality as the example - ie with a nice windows height, automatic mouse wheel scroll and the menu working too?

I tried to deconstruct the beoplay page but had no luck at all.

The code is available on GitHub here: https://github.com/truedaz/scroll-site

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **[fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)**.

It works with anchor links and allows to link them with any menu or navigation you want to create.

Works with touch events too and it has plenty of options to configure such as the scrolling speed, the easing, loops, overflow for each section, callbacks (very useful to add animations)...ec.

And, it works even in old browsers such as IE 8 !

- [Web page](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)
- [Github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)
- [Living demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)